# The sample space of two six-sided dice and the idea that sets are unordered

Tags: probability-theory

Take the common probability theory example of two six-sided dice. I saw the sample space for this example written as

$$\{ \{1, 1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 1\}, \dots, \{5, 6\}, \{6, 5\}, \{6, 6\} \}$$

But we know that sets are unordered. This means, for instance, that $\{1, 2\}$ is the same as $\{2, 1\}$, and $\{5, 6\}$ is the same as $\{6, 5\}$. So shouldn't this actually just be

$$\{ \{1, 1\}, \{1, 2\}, \dots, \{5, 6\}, \{6, 6\} \}$$

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in what you saw written, but whether your expression or Ethan Bolker's is correct depends whether the dice are distinguishable. If the dice are indistinguishable, then your interpretation is correct, the outcomes $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are the same outcome and that outcome should only appear once. If the dice are different colours, or they are rolled one after the other, then the outcomes $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are different outcomes, and they should be written as 2-tuples.

Comment: The real difficulty with the "indistinguishable" approach is that getting a $5$ and a $6$ has twice the probability of two $6$s so you cannot use simple counting arguments.  A minor additional difficulty with the set notation is that $\{6,6\}=\{6\}$ and $\{6\}$ looks strange as the outcome of throwing two dice.

Comment: @Henry Well said. What the OP saw is wrong in both the distinguishable and indistinguishable cases.

Comment: @Henry good point. The outcome $\{6,6\}$ is different from the outcome $\{6\}$ (i.e. the outcome of only one die roll). The outcomes are actually multisets, i.e. sets where there is also a concept of 'multiplicity'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Answer (score 5):

Whoever wrote the sample space that way made a mistake. It should be
$$
\{(1,1),  (1,2), \ldots , (6,6)\},
$$
the $36$ ordered pairs of single die outcomes.. $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are the same set but $(1,2) \ne (2,1)$: throwing $1$ on the first die and $2$ on the second is not the same event as the reverse.

Comment: Ahh, so the outcomes should actually be written as 2-tuples, rather than as sets?

Comment: Yes, but see @1Rock 's better answer.

Comment: I think this answer is better for leaning simple probability

Comment: @Henry Perhaps so. I wonder what the author of the OP's text meant. Probably ordered pairs.